# Meaning of aniya

Tags: naming

Assalaam o Alaikum 
My daughter's name is aniya.  From what we saw on the internet it meant concern and lovinh. But someone recently told us that it's meaning in arabic is prisoner.  Can somebody help us with this? We are quite puzzled. Also aniya in Hebrew and polish means god has given much i think. Is it ok to keep this name in islam?

Comment: Names are a matter of interpretation (and the meaning my differ from languge or dialect to an other), and I don't know of any word in Arabic (standard or fasih language) which is even close to the meaning "prisoner". If you think the name is good and has no clear offense to tawheed just keep it. Like if you called your daughter servant of Buddah or servant of Money or what ever may look as a name related to shirk! I've lately seen that questions on naming have been closed as off-topic that's why I won't post this as an answer!

Comment: Jazakallah for the insight

Answer (score 2):

in lane's dictionary: http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/lane/ppages/Lane-P560060.gif : it means also "lovely, humble or submissive woman" :

[image: Lane-P560060-ganin]

in baranov's arabic-russian there is another "ganiya" which means "suffering, unhappy", but in lane's dictionary there is no such word: http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/lane/ppages/Lane-P560574.gif :

[image: Lane-P560574-ganin]

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning more clearly..it means according to this a woman in captive?

Comment: @sumaiya my answer here covers this i guess https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40875/in-what-sense-are-wives-captives-in-the-hadith-they-are-but-captives-with/40883#40883