# Clarification and questions about this Hadith

Tags: hadith-interpretation, husband-wife

Below is the Hadith regarding which I want clarifications.

> It was narrated that: Sulaiman bin Amr bin Ahwas said: “My father told
> me that he was present at the Farewell Pilgrimage with the Messenger
> of Allah. He praised and glorified Allah, and reminded and exhorted
> (the people). Then he said: 'I enjoin good treatment of women, for
> they are prisoners with you, and you have no right to treat them
> otherwise unless they commit clear indecency. If they do that, then
> forsake them in their beds and hit them, but without causing injury or
> leaving a mark. If they obey you, then do not seek means of annoyance
> against them. You have rights over your women and your women have
> rights over you. Your rights over your women are that they are not to
> allow anyone whom you dislike to tread on your bedding (furniture),
> nor allow anyone whom you dislike to enter your houses. And their
> right over you are that you should treat them kindly with regard to
> their clothing and food.' ”
>
> Sunan Ibn Majah 1851 https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1851

To quote "....for they are prisoners with you", why did the Messenger of Allah call the wife as the prisoner of man? Isn't 'prisoner' a harsh word to be used in this context? I deduced that this is being said about the wife and not for the general women from the line "...then forsake them in their beds". Please correct me if I am wrong here.

To quote "...and hit them, but without causing injury or leaving a mark.",

1. So does this mean that beating the wife is justified in case she has done something indecent?
2. What types of indecency come under this?
3. Is this mandatory? Can't she be forgiven and given another chance?
4. Can a woman beat their husband too if she comes to know about any indecency done by him? If yes, then are the rules the same? If not, then why not, and what are the other ways in which women can handle such situations?
5. Is there any mention of any verse in the Quran which supports this Hadith?

Please clarify!

Comment: Please ask one question per post and research on your own before asking. Questions which show laziness and do not demonstrate any research effort are discouraged. You can't expect people to repeat things for every new person who comes across them. The meaning of captives is covered here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77442/ The verse  [Quran 4:34](https://quran.com/4/34?translations=20) is also relevant.