# Did Muhammad ever instruct anyone to write down the Quran or Hadith?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah

I am wondering if at any points during his lifetime he instructed people to write down the Quran and Hadiths or were they simply remembered and written down later voluntarily?

Comment: Muhammed had scribes who where called to write down the revelation.

Comment: Called by whom?

 So "revelation" I believe pertains exclusively to the Quran. How about the Hadith? Also, Can you provide sources for what you said?

Comment: I"ve provided enough in my answers on that topic.

Comment: My questions are specific.  But if you don't want to provide a source or answer the specific questions then that's your choice.

Comment: your question is not specific as it has two parts writing down qur'an which I covered in [Prophet Muhammad was illiterate who wrote the quran then](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28370/prophet-muhammad-saw-was-illiterate-who-wrote-the-quran-then/28371#28371) and writing down sunnah which others [see here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/940/is-it-true-that-the-prophet-forbade-writing-hadiths) and myself covered in [Do these hadith discredit all other hadiths](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35476/do-these-hadith-discredit-all-other-hadiths/35477#35477).

Comment: For a question to be specific it doesn't mean it is composed of only one part. Yes I am asking about both the Quran and the Hadith which are specific questions. Also, fine, you say this has been covered already, why not provide a link then to the posts which answer my questions?

Comment: Well both parts can be marked as duplicates of former questions that's the issue.

Comment: Yes but that would mean you need to show me those former questions and show me how they are duplicates.

Comment: I thought you were able to seek, as we don't like duplicate questions. Once I had a pc in front of me it was a matter of 30 sec.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Prophet ﷺ had scribes among the Sahabah who wrote down the Quran, for their details see for example: [البداية والنهاية](https://archive.org/stream/FP160921/05_160925#page/n486/mode/2up) ([translation](https://archive.org/details/AlSiraAlNabawiyyaTheLifeOfProphetMuhammadSAWIbnKathirVolume4_201707/page/n509)). Writing Hadith was initially forbidden but was permitted later, see [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/22394) .

The scribes did so on his instruction, for example the narration of [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/66/12) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/206), [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/31) etc. that has been cited in البداية:

> "When the words of Almighty God came down, 'Those believers who stay back and those who strive hard in God's cause are not equal' (surat al-Nisa'; IV, v.95), the Messenger of God (SAAS) called out to me and said, '**Write down**, "Those believers who stay back and those who strive hard in God's cause are not equal.'"

Comment: Sure, but I didn't ask if anyone wrote the Quran/Hadith down, I asked if the prophet himself instructed anyone to do so.

Comment: @JohnDoe A scribe is a person who is specifically appointed to write things down, and does so upon dictation. Anyways I have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm also wondering if you know whether or not Muhammad instructed for the Quran to then be compiled into a book and that this book be then transported around the world like we see today. Do we have evidence of that as well?